# Что делать с явно заготовленным самоответом?

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

В очереди проверок наткнулся на вопрос с признаками низкого качества:
[Как в питоне вычислить выражение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231361/420098)
Ниже уже был самоответ (дан с разницей в несколько секунд), явно заготовленный автором вопроса заранее...

На вопрос "зачем так делать?", ответ я примерно представляю.
Подскажите ответ на вопрос "что делать с такими экспресс вопрос-ответами?"

Comment: Хорошие самоответы здесь только приветствуются! Не забывайте, что главное - качество вопроса и ответа. Авторство и время - не важны.

Comment: «с разницей в несколько секунд» — в ноль секунд. В форме создания вопроса есть специальная галочка «Ответить на собственный вопрос» ;)

Comment: Теперь более актуален вопрос, что делать, когда один и тот же ответ копипастят по всем похожим вопросам)

Comment: @insolor ага, или копипастят сам [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231791/420098) в текст [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231791/420098)  ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тоже самое, что и с любым другим вопросом. Вам нравится — +1. Не нравится? — -1. Вопрос следует закрыть? — закрыть. Не уверены / не имеете четкого мнения — ничего.

Comment: _"- Где мы? - На воздушном шаре."_ - в чём смысл давать совершенно точный, но совершенно бесполезный ответ на нормальный вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy Чего-то я не понял ;) Какой ответ бесполезный? O чем ты? ;)

Comment: Твой ответ. По сути сводится к "думайте сами".

Comment: @Qwertiy Я сказал, что такой вопрос ничем не отличается от любого другого, и что с ним не надо ничего особенного делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы невнимательно прочитали первое же предложение - ответ по сути в нем.

Answer (score 18):

Как минимум, ничего. Во-первых, вопрос вполне нормальный. Во-вторых, полезный ответ уже есть. Можно пару плюсиков поставить за вопрос и ответ.

Answer (score 8):

> **что делать с такими экспресс вопрос-ответами?**

В большинстве случаев поставить плюс к вопросу и ответу. Это отличный способ поблагодарить автора за время и усилие, которое он вложил в его написание! Сообщество призывает всех участников отвечать на свои вопросы. Вот выдержка из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> *Мы призываем всех участников отвечать на свои вопросы:*
>
> - *если у вас есть вопрос, на который вы заранее знаете ответ;*
> - *если вы хотите поделиться своими знаниями с сообществом, то есть    чтобы ваши коллеги, да и вы сами, в будущем при возникновении
>
>   аналогичной, либо схожей проблемы смогли быстро найти решение;*
>
> *опубликуйте вопрос c вашим ответом к нему!*

---

> **В очереди проверок наткнулся на вопрос с признаками низкого
> качества:**

А это как минимум странно. Если сообщество призывает всех участников отвечать на свои вопросы, то значит сообщество благодарно таким участникам. Намерения голосующих за закрытие таких вопросов с самоответами не совсем понятны. Как мне кажется, подобные действия (выпады) противоречат [ключевым ценностям сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values).

Comment: Все проще - конкретно этот вопрос достаточно плохо написан.

Comment: А по каким критериям (конкретно) вы это определили?

Comment: Я прочитал вопрос и посчитал его плохо сформулированным. Флаг поставил даже

Comment: То есть вы руководствовались исключительно только своим личным субъективным восприятием?

Comment: Именно так, чисто субъективно, никто мне не нашептывал и не проплачивал

Comment: @Sevastopol' речь идет именно о качестве вопроса и полезности ответа...

Comment: Тогда почему вы так уверенно утверждаете, что: `конкретно этот вопрос достаточно плохо написан`, а не пишите, например, "я считаю, что..." или "по моему мнению..."? Это же ваше личное мнение, основанное исключительно только на вашем же личном субъективном восприятии, а не обоснованное определенно по каким-то критериям. И еще: а что собственно означает ваша фраза `вопрос достаточно плохо написан`? Не могу понять ее логику.

Comment: @Kromster а что именно плохо сформулировано? Конкретная задача поставлена — посчитать математическую формулу, что ещё нужно?

Comment: Скорее всего вопрос отправлен в очередь проверок автоматически как подозрительно короткий - Дух ставит такие тревоги.

Comment: @andreymal собственно вы и сами в своем комментарии все указалаи - ни описания формулы, ни самой формулы нет, толи с eval, толи без (см. историю правок). Сейчас стало лучше.

Comment: @Kromster «см. историю правок» — ох и правда, теперь понятно)