# Что делать, если участник копирует один и тот же ответ на несколько (формально подходящих) вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Недавно участник задал вопрос с самоответом:
[Как в питоне вычислить простое математическое выражение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1231360/1365)
Участник привел его в порядок, получил заслуженные плюсы, после этого начал копировать ответ на другие похожие вопросы.

Примеры:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231759
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231755

Насколько это допустимо и нужно ли с этим бороться?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что делать с явно заготовленным самоответом?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11292)

Comment: Либо потерли ответы, либо ссылки не те. Ответов автора там не наблюдается

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, да, сейчас ответы удалены.

Comment: Формально большинство вопросов на SO однотипны/цикличны. Так или иначе, если вопрос не закрывается как клон, то и ответ будет более-менее копипастой.

Comment: Ничего, если ответ подходит. ;)

Comment: Если считаете **вопросы** одинаковыми - надо закрывать как дубль... нет?

Comment: @Harry не считаю вопросы одинаковыми, считаю похожими, но не идентичными.

Comment: @insolor Тогда, если ответ таки отвечает на оба вопроса - по-моему, все в рамках допустимого.

Comment: @Harry, понятно, что формально это в рамках правил. Но с одной стороны это на грани накрутки, с другой стороны копипаста одного и того же ответа не увеличивает количество знаний на сайте.

Comment: @insolor *Теоретически* цель ruSO -- база знаний. Зашел, поискал, нашел ответ. В рамках этого ответ - пусть и одинаковый - должен присутствовать... *Практически* все еще хуже, никто ничего не ищет, сходу задает вопрос, причем в основном "быстренько решили за меня", но и тут ответ лучше давать прямо в вопросе...

Comment: @Harry 1 - по факту - обоих вопросах уже есть ответы с более-менее стандартными способами решения проблемы, а тут участник копипастит свой велосипед, причем не самый лучший (на мой вкус). 2 - через поиск найдутся все три вопроса, в разных вариациях, с немного разными вариантами ответов. Технически да, наверное стоило бы задубликатить все на один вопрос (тем более что у меня есть возможность сделать это одним голосом), но я не уверен на 100% что это дубликаты, ну и все равно не смог бы сделать ничего с дублями ответов.

Comment: @Harry считайте, что я хотел переложить ответственность с себя на сообщество и модераторов. В итоге вопросы "задубликачены", дубли ответов удалены, это меня волне устраивает.

Comment: @Harry ну да, можно было бы поставить тревогу "не ответ" на ответы, и получить "отклонённые - не следует использовать сигнал тревоги, чтобы указать на неточность или неверность ответа". Можно было бы еще минусы поставить, но мне жаль портить круглое число репутации)

Comment: Как думаю я:
Если два, три, четыре, короче не важно сколько похожих вопросов. Если вопросы поставлены совершенно по разному и ответ на всех вопросах правильный, то почему бы и не продублировать этот ответ?

Answer (score 9):

Ничего, если ответ подходит. Помечать как "не ответ", если не подходит. Плюс если там например какая-то ссылка, то это может быль спам. Но в конкретном случае, я считаю, что это нормально. Ответы отвечают на вопрос, и никак не могут быть спамом.

...тем страннее, что их удалили.

Comment: У модераторов есть отдельные нотификации в подобных случаях полной копипасты.

Comment: @A K т.е. такие ответы всё-таки запрещены?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Да нет, значит, что они потенциально могут быть спамом или чем-то еще — значит проверить их надо. Ну а так не запрещены. AFAIK

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Может и не запрещены, но очень не рекомендуются. Если в ответе найдут ошибку, то что, ее лезть исправлять в нескольких местах сразу?

Answer (score 7):

Если у двух разных вопросов одинаковые ответы .. то сверить вопросы, может быть они на самом деле одинаковы, поставить флаг за закрытие, как "дубликат". Предпочтение отдавать более старым вопрос и с более хорошими/подробными ответами.